# What is the blow-up of a variety at the ideal$(x_1^2,x_1x_2,x_2^2)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I try to prove that the blow-up of $\mathbb{A}^2$ at the ideal $(x_1,x_2)$ is isomorphism to the blow-up of $\mathbb{A}^2$ at the ideal $(x_1^2,x_1x_2,x_2^2)$.

But I can't prove it. I want to calculate the blow-up at $(x_1^2,x_1x_2,x_2^2)$ directly,because I know that the blow-up at $(x_1,x_2)$.(If you want to know about the blow-up at $(x_1,x_2)$, you can refer to *Algebraic geometry by Andreas Gathmann(2021), Sec 9.*)

Please give me a hint, whether it's about the calculation of this blow-up or the establishment of this isomorphic relationship. Thank you so much!

Comment: So you want to show that gluing $k[x,y,xy/x^2, y^2/x^2]$, $k[x,y,x^2/xy, y^2/xy]$ and $k[x,y,x^2/y^2, xy/y^2]$ together is the same as gluing $k[x,y,x/y]$ and $k[x,y,y/x]$. Two of the rings in the first list are equal to the rings in the second list, so the main point is to show that the third ring in the first list is extraneous.

Comment: It also follows because the Rees algebra of this ideal is a Veronese subring of the Rees algebra of $(x_0,x_1)$, so the Proj's are isomorphic.

Comment: @EnnioMoricone Thank you very much for your answer, but I am not familiar with **Rees algebra**. Can you use a simpler method or provide me with a more detailed answer?

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Thank you very much for your answer,I will try asking questions on another website.